# a-frame glb scales with window

Tags: entity, scale, augmented-reality, proportions

My glb file is changing shape based on the percentage of the window. So if you view it on a phone that is vertical, it's tall and skinny and if you view it horizontally on a phone it is short really wide. Is there a way to constrain the proportions so it doesn't stretch on the x and y axis?

I have tried depth="1" height="1" width="1" and scale="1 1 1" but neither keep the proportions correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the `embedded` parameter to your `<a-scene>`

```html
<a-scene embedded> </a-scene>
```

more infomation:
https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/embedded.html#sidebar